# Rails - converting data from database to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, json, forms

I'm trying to create a timeline, with a form for a user to input a new event. I've decided to use the timeline from http://timeline.verite.co/ - I can create a form for each user to input a new event, and save that event to the database no problem. However, what I'm having trouble figuring out is:

a) Getting the data from the database and turning it into the correct JSON format that the timeline would be happy with - I have no idea where to start with this! Do I need to name the columns in the database with the same name as the JSON attributes, e.g. "caption"? And how do I then turn this into JSON?

b) How do I generate the JSON doc on the fly? The code requires a link to a JSON doc with the data.

This is the only way I can figure out how to do this - as if I was to generate a JSON doc for each user and insert each new event, then read from this, then surely there is some security issues with a JSON doc being easier to download by someone who doesn't own it, than data in a database?

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated - I'm pretty new to Rails and haven't had to really touch JSON yet! Thank you.

In case it helps, the data format required by the timeline is this:

```
{
  "timeline":
  {
      "headline":"The Main Timeline Headline Goes here",
      "type":"default",
      "text":"<p>Intro body text goes here, some HTML is ok</p>",
      "asset": {
          "media":"http://yourdomain_or_socialmedialink_goes_here.jpg",
          "credit":"Credit Name Goes Here",
          "caption":"Caption text goes here"
      },
      "date": [
          {
              "startDate":"2011,12,10",
              "endDate":"2011,12,11",
              "headline":"Headline Goes Here",
              "text":"<p>Body text goes here, some HTML is OK</p>",
              "tag":"This is Optional",
              "asset": {
                  "media":"http://twitter.com/ArjunaSoriano/status/164181156147900416",
                  "thumbnail":"optional-32x32px.jpg",
                  "credit":"Credit Name Goes Here",
                  "caption":"Caption text goes here"
              }
          }
      ],
      "era": [
          {
              "startDate":"2011,12,10",
              "endDate":"2011,12,11",
              "headline":"Headline Goes Here",
              "text":"<p>Body text goes here, some HTML is OK</p>",
              "tag":"This is Optional"
          } 

        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can easily turn Ruby Hash to JSON with `data_hash.to_json`. How to put data from the DB into hash is another question, it depends much on your DB structure and your knowledge of Ruby and ActiveRecord.

Comment: Ok, could I pull the data out of the database as a Ruby object and then convert it to JSON? How would I do this and then get it into the correct format? As you might be able to tell, my knowledge on the inner workings of the db is fairly limited - I've only created applications that create and read data, never tampering with it in this way. Any help would be great, but I'm afraid you might have to spell it out a bit for me! Thanks.

Comment: I agree with **saverio**'s answer, for JSON structure as complex as you need it is much better to use JSON templates rather than `to_json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `#to_json` is not really an option, too complex.

Try to use JSON templates with JBuilder (see https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

You can even use partials and cache, like a normal ERB view.

Comment: That looks like just what I am after, thanks for that. However, how would I then pass the resulting JSON into the timeline, as it requests a path to the JSON to use as the source data? Thanks.

Comment: The wiew will be served by your server with a route, something like `http://www.yourserver.com/timelines/42.json` should output the JSON corresponding to the timeline #42

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your json object into a string and stored in the database as blob type, then while retrieving you can use

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(VALUE)
```

to convert the string to json

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). It will let you export simple and complex json structures with views in your rails application. It's extremely easy to set up.